# Running two different Jenkins versions on same Linux Cent OS VMs

Tags: linux, jenkins, centos, cicd

I have one Jenkins version running on port 8080 in my CentOS VM.
I want to install another Jenkins version on a different port but on the same CentOS VM.
How could I do that? Btw I usually start my jenkins using command 'sudo service jenkins start'.

Comment: `How could I do that?` Run virtual centos with another jenking. Run it in docker, or in podman. Or download different jenking sources, if needed compile it and run it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different **JENKINS_HOME** and a different **port**. To be safe, also a different binary location (if you autoupdate, issues otherwise). *You do not need to build your own binary.*

`java -DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/configs -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8100`

There's info on the net as to how to change depending how you installed/what's your service wrapper, eg:  [Manage multiple service instances with systemctl](https://web.archive.org/web/20210508230640/https://opensource.com/article/20/12/multiple-service-instances-systemctl)

The linked example for **systemctl** suggest one service file can be used to manage different instances but it still invokes different conf. We still use **init.d** so, it's two files in `init.d`, with the different names (Jenkins_A, Jenkins_B), and different values; pretty rudimentary but functional. Ultimately is the same effect. We do the same for multiple other tools (eg:Nexus, SonarQube), too.

*Also, this question also best asked/answered on [Superuser SE](https://superuser.com/tags/jenkins) in a more general context (eg: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/958148/centos7-restart-multiple-instances-of-a-service-with-one-command) ).*

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in linux do we have to create another service file?

Comment: Elaborated Answer. An upvote would be nice ..